# jquery dynamic unique id for <tr> table

Tags: jquery

I'm using this code:
jsfiddle.net/EyruX/1/

and I add ID to each table row - tr

in the link example i add id='111'

I also add delete button that delete the row (with ajax) according the row id (tr id).

When I click ADD I need that the code will not only add new row (like now) but also will add unique ID to each tr ID.

for instance - the first row/tr id will be : id = "new1"
the second will be: id = "new2"
and etc.

Can you help me with it?

Comment: The question is: _Can you help me with it?_.

Comment: In your fiddle you are adding new `<table>` not new rows. Do you want new ID in the table or in the second row of each table like id="111" is?

Answer (score 6):

If you are also using jQueryUI there is a ready-made solution: [`$.uniqueId`](http://api.jqueryui.com/uniqueId/).

If not, it's easy to implement it yourself (code lifted from the UI [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.core.js#L75-L81) and adapted slightly):

```
var uuid = 0;
$.fn.uniqueId = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        if ( !this.id ) {
            this.id = "ui-id-" + (++uuid);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var i =0;
$(function(){
    $('#clone').click(function(){
        i=i+1;
        $('#main').append($('<input>').attr('type','button').attr('id','param'+i).val(i));
    });
})
```

You can see how it works in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rSSrs/1/)

And don't use .clone(), use .append instead or the id won't change.